# Angular-Schema-Form Change FORM on SCHEMA change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonschema, angular-schema-form

I have got a problem with changing json schema with angular schema form.
If I set up schema like in code like this

```
$scope.schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Schema number ONE",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {..
```

it works and renders whole form properly as I want.
But I want to load data from web service.

So I tried to set up schema to nothing and then change it by clicking button, but it didnt work. I mean, i got schema from service, but form do not change.
 For example something like this in code.

```
$scope.schema = {};
$scope.changeSchema= function(){
    $scope.schema = {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "  Schema number two that I want",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
}
```

What I want is to select schema to load and change form to schema i selected.
Thank you very much.

Comment: you posted two code snippets that look like they are mostly identical; I don't really see a question here or a statement of what's wrong.  "It didn't work" is never a good problem statement.

Comment: Um, these snippets are not really important. I just wanted to show that I am changing schema.

And despite the schema changed, the rendered Form was the same.

Comment: you haven't shown the full code that makes this change, but I suspect you didn't issue the `$scope.$broadcast('schemaFormRedraw')` event which is documented here: https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#updating-form

Comment: That seems to be what i have been looking for.
But,

"[Error] Error: Not implemented. Only type "object" allowed at root level of schema."

after using it.

Answer (score 1):

As Claies pointed out in their comment, you need to trigger a schemaFormRedraw broadcast. However on load the error is due to validation on the schema that you have as `{}`, this would need to be a temporary schema, something along these lines should work:

```
$scope.schema = { "type": "object", "properties": {} }};
$scope.changeSchema = function() {
    $scope.schema = {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "  Schema number two that I want",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {...}
    }
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormRedraw');
}
```